# Microsoft Entity Framework: List property on Model is not updated in database after adding data and saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Been stuck on this longer than I'd like to admit. I have a data model which contains a list of objects. In the method where I'm adding objects to the list it shows that the data is being stored, however once I tried to get the data from another method it isn't there anymore. Changes to other properties of the data will update, therefore my guess is that there is in issue where EF isn't registering the updated data within the list.

This is the data Model I'm trying to update

```cs
 public long Id { get; set; }
 [Required(ErrorMessage ="Team Name is required")]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team Location is required")]
 public string Location { get; set; }
 public List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();
```

And here is how I'm adding data to the list property

```
  team.Players.Add(player);
  context.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified;
  context.SaveChanges();
```

I've tried everything else I could find online, but nothing worked. I'm newer to EF so hopefully this is a easy error on my part

EDIT: Clarification

DataModel for Player:

```
  public class Player
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Player FirstName is required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team Name is required")]

        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DataModel Team

```
public class Team
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Team Name is required")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team Location is required")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public List<Player> PlayerList = new List<Player>();
    }
}
```

Data Base Context:

```
 public class TeamListContext : DbContext
    {
        public TeamListContext(DbContextOptions<TeamListContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }
```

Endpoint to create team(player is virtually the same)

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<Team>> CreateTeam(Team team)
        {
            //save team to Teams set in teamlistcontext 
            context.Teams.Add(team);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return team;

        }
```

Snippets from method where I'm trying to add player to team

```
 Team team =  await context.Teams.FindAsync(teamId);
 Player player =  await context.Players.FindAsync(playerId);

//other logic not affecting issue

//
team.PlayerList.Add(player);
context.Entry(team).State = EntityState.Modified
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception?  Or stepping through in debugger?

Comment: @devlincarnate there's no exceptions being thrown and the debugger shows the Players list being updated within my put method. However, when I call a get route they update is no longer there.

Comment: In the method where you are selecting the items, you could use .AsNoTracking() if you dont intend to iterate or modify any of the items returned within the same scope/context (ie selecting for view only). asnotracking will force EF to go to the database and get fresh data and not register anything in the changetracker

Comment: check the output window and see the query generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ICollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` and make `PlayerList` a property instead of a field by adding `{ get; set; }`

```
public class Player
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Player FirstName is required")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team Name is required")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Team Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Team Location is required")]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> PlayerList { get; set; }
}
```

To add a `Player` to a `Team` something like that is needed:

```
var team =  await context.Teams.FindAsync (teamId);
var player = new Player { FirstName = "firstname", LastName = "lastname" };

team.PlayerList.Add (player);
context.SaveChanges ();
```

You don't need to set the `team` state to `Modified` because nothing has changed that needs to be commited to the database. Only the `player` will be inserted in the database.

EDIT - for your comment on multiple contexts:

It's important that you call `context.SaveChanges ()` on all contexts. Only the instance of `context` knowns what has been changed and can generate the sql insert/update/delete statements. To make sure that different contexts (or even when you use only one context) will made database changes atomic you can use `TransactionScope` to make sure either all changes are written to the database or nothing happens at all. Example:

```
public void DoWork ()
{
    // make sure you have MSDTC configured otherwise the TransactionScope will not work.
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope ()) 
    {
        Action1 ();
        Action2 ();

        // This will persist it to the database - COMMIT
        scope.Complete (); 
    } 
}

public void Action1 ()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext ()) 
    {
        // Do some work...

        context.SaveChanges ();
    }
}

public void Action2 ()
{
    using (var otherContext = new DbContext ()) 
    {
        // Do some work...

        otherContext.SaveChanges ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented your advice, but still to no success. Though, I think I've narrowed down the issue to certain methods having different context, I just need to find a way to make sure all methods are dealing with the same context